# Getting an error of the query contains a malformed ending

Tags: jpa

I am trying to query from my table named tblusers, but it gives me an error stated above. The query checks for the username and password as well as its privilege/role which is student or an admin. I am new to JPA/JPQL so I'm unsure on what is wrong with my query, this is what I get from tutorials.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Tblusers.findByAdmin", query = "SELECT t FROM Tblusers t
WHERE t.username = :username, t.password = :password, t.privilege = 'admin'")
```

Comment: I would start with replacing `,` with `AND` in where clause

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: @Piro please post answers as answers not as comments. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli that was just suggestion. Not an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer from Piro:

> Replace , with AND